# Including or uploading a file using selenium in java

Tags: java, selenium

```
<input type="button" class="button white-button custom-modal-button" id="btnAttachment" ng-click="openAttachment()" value="Import CSV template">

enter code here

WebElement browse =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"btnAttachment\"]"));
//pass the path of the file to be uploaded using Sendkeys method
browse.sendKeys("\\Users\\nilaapps13\\Desktop\\lead.csv");
```

when using sendkeys function it  opens up the upload window , but not choosing the file . is there any other way?

Comment: If you close the opened window, then it is choosing or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File("/users/chennai4/downloads/lead.csv");
            StringSelection stringSelection= new StringSelection(file.getAbsolutePath());
           //Copy to clipboard 
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
            Robot robot = new Robot();
          // Cmd + Tab is needed since it launches a Java app and the browser looses focus
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
            robot.delay(500);

            //Open Goto window
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);

            //Paste the clipboard value
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);

            //Press Enter key to close the Goto window and Upload window
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.delay(1000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

this is the code i used working perfectly in mac os..

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to press enter ie send Enter key using sendKeys

Answer (score 0):

the upload window is a Windows popup and not browser popup so selenium commands dont work in this case.

You can make use of java Robot and StringSelection class.
Step 1: copy file path to system clipboard
Step 2: paste file path to upload window (send keys Ctrl+V) and then send Enter key.

add following packages

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

use StringSelection class for copy and paste operations.

```
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection("\\Users\\nilaapps13\\Desktop\\lead.csv");
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
```

use Robot class to send keyboard events

```
Robot robot = new Robot();

robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: This is the best way . it worked perfectly fine ...  ty :-)